# Empty Cache & Hard Reload vs Clear Site Data

Tags: google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-devtools, reload

What is the difference between `Empty Cache & Hard Reload` and `Clear Site Data`?

When your Chrome devtools are open, you can right click on reload and select `Empty Cache & Hard Reload`.

In your Chrome devtool, under Application, you can select `Clear Storage` and click a button that says `Clear site data`.

I've tried reading about each of these and don't understand the difference, any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: As you can see there's much more to site data than just cache.

Comment: Yeah! I have a decent understanding of `Empty Cache & Hard Reload`, but can't find as much our there about `Clear site data`. It *seems* like `Clear site` data actually does more than `Empty Cache & Hard Reload`, but am unsure if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Normal Reload:** Uses Cached Data.

**Hard Reload:** Forces browser to re-download items and reload. It is possible that used resources may come from a cached version.

**Empty Cache & Hard Reload:** Cache for the page is cleared completely and everything must be re-downloaded as required.

[normal vs hard reload and cache](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/empty-cache-hard-reload-chrome)

Comment: This is helpful, however, the main question revolves around the `Clear Site Data` in Chrome devtools and `Empty Cache & Hard Reload`.

Comment: `Clear Site Data` has other advantages over `hard reload` e.g. Using `Clear site data` browser storage can be cleared where same is not possible in hard reload.
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data)

Comment: Second thing is `Clear site data` is internal and can only be used by site developer, whereas a layman can do hard reload of his own.

Answer (score 0):

**Normal Reload**: Hey, use the cache, also validate the resources for not modified response.

**Hard Reload**: Basically yelling at the browser to load the contents from the server again.

**Empty Cache & Hard Reload**: Didn't you get it, clear the cache and hard reload again. Don't forget to clear additional downloaded files by the js.

**Clear Site Data**: Do you have one shot button to clear everything? Oh Yes, the magic button is "Clear Site Data". It removes `"Cache Storage", "Cookies", "ServiceWorkers", "IndexedDB", "LocalStorage", "Application Cache"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Shadow. Are you able to provide an example resource(s) that is reloaded during each different level of reloading?